# Struct.unpack and Length of Byte Object

Tags: python

I have the following code (data is a byte object):

```
    v = sum(struct.unpack('!%sH' % int(len(data)/2), data))
```

The part that confuses me is the %sH in the format string and the % int(len(data)/2

How exactly is this part of the code working? What is the length of a byte object? And what exactly is this taking the sum of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a byte string `data` such as:

```
>>> data = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
>>> data
'\x01\x02\x03\x04'
```

The length is the number of bytes (or characters) in the byte string:

```
>>> len(data)
4
```

So this is equivalent to your code:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('!2H', data)
(258, 772)
```

This tells the `struct` module to use the following [format characters](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters):

- `!` - use network (big endian) mode
- `2H` - unpack 2 x unsigned shorts (16 bits each)

And it returns two integers which correspond to the data we supplied:

```
>>> '%04x' % 258
'0102'
>>> '%04x' % 772
'0304'
```

All your code does is automatically calculate the number of `unsigned shorts` on the fly

```
>>> struct.unpack('!%sH' % int(len(data)/2), data)
(258, 772)
```

But the `int` convesion is unnecessary, and it shouldn't really be using the `%s` placeholder as that is for string substitution:

```
>>> struct.unpack('!%dH' % (len(data)/2), data)
(258, 772)
```

So unpack returns two integers relating to the unpacking of 2 `unsigned shorts` from the data byte str. Sum then returns the sum of these:

```
>>> sum(struct.unpack('!%dH' % (len(data)/2), data))
1030
```

Answer (score 1):

### How your code works:

- You are interpreting the byte structure of `data`

  - `struct.unpack` uses a string to determine the byte format of the data you want to interpret
  - Given the format `stuct.unpack` returns an iterable of the interpreted data.
- You then sum the interable.

### Byte Formatting

To interpret your data you are passing, you create a [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#FormatCharacters) to tell Python what form `data` comes in. Specifically the `%sH` part is a short hand for *this number of unsigned shorts* which you then format to say the exact number of `unsigned short` you want.

In this case the number is:

```
int(len(data) / 2)
```

because an `unsigned short` is normally 2 bytes wide.